# Exception when change Border property from other thread

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, wpf-controls

i've a component in WPF, this component use a border and i use the border Background property to change my background color of entire component.

The problem, are when i try alternate between two different colors, with a timer, the invalidOperationException are thrown.
"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it". On timer method i put the code to change the border properties in Dispatcher object.

```
            mainBorder.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate() 
            {
                mainBorder.BorderBrush = myBrush;
               mainBorder.Background = myBrush;
            }, null);
```

but the exception are thrown and i not understand what i doing wrong! For example in the same time i doing it code

```
lbHolderServico.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate()
{
    lbHolderServico.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(HoldLabelsFontColor);
}, null);
```

to change the label font color and everything works fine.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to define the brushes/animations as resources and start the animations or assign the brushes when needed.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you create and set values for `myBrush` on the UI thread, as well.

`mainBorder`, being a border, has a thread affinity.  However, [Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx) also has thread affinity, as it is derived from [DispatcherObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.aspx).

(Your second example works because you're creating a new brush in the UI thread, not using one created elsewhere...)

Comment: Off course!! you're rigth.. Thanks help i just create myBrush on the UI thread.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: That, of course, would work -provided the OP isn't trying to change the brush values.